# menu and submenu editable on backoffice

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I'm trying to make a menu with submenu in php because I want it to be possible to add or remove a menu / submenu, but I'm not able to do the submenu part ... the html of the submenu is in the form of a comment, so not be running as code as it is not working ...

this is the code:

```
            <?php
                require_once "conexao.php";
                $conexao = conexao_db();
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_visivel LIKE '1'";
                $registo = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($registo)!=0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($registo)) {
                        $menu_titulo = $row['menu_titulo'];
                        $menu_link = $row['menu_link'];
                        if ($row['menu_link']=='quinta.php') {
                            $cor = "style='color: black;'";
                        } else {
                            $cor = "style='color: grey;'";
                        }
                        echo "<li><a href='".$row['menu_link']."' $cor>".$row['menu_titulo']."</a>";
                        /*<ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                         </ul>*/
                         echo "</li>";
                    }

                }
            ?>

          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

please help me!! :D

Comment: what is your question

Comment: Also `echo "<li><a href='".$row['menu_link']."' ".$cor.">".$row['menu_titulo']."</a>";`

Comment: @mplungjan is the same... xD

Comment: @mlegg i want to put the submenu working with php, but so far I've only been able to do this with the menu ...

Comment: Update your question with details instead of commenting.

Comment: which details??